# How to conditionally replace Spark SQL array values using SQL language?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this column inside myTable:

| myColumn |
| --- |
| [red, green] |
| [green, green, red] |

I need to modify it so that I can replace red with 1, green with 2:

| myColumn |
| --- |
| [1, 2] |
| [2, 2, 1] |

In short, is there a way to apply case clause for each element in the array, row wise?

The closest I've gotten so far:

```sql
select replace(replace(to_json(myColumn), 'red', 1), 'green', 2)
```

On the other hand, in case we have a column of strings, I could simply use:

```sql
select (
  case
    when myColumn='red' then 1
    when myColumn='green' then 2
  end
) from myTable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could perform a simple transform (Spark 3 onwards)

```
select transform(myColumn, value ->
  case value
    when 'red' then 1
    when 'green' then 2
  end
from myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the dataframe has registered a temporary view named `tmp`, use the following SQL statement to get the result.

```
sql = """
    select
        collect_list(
            case col
                when 'red' then 1
                when 'green' then 2
            end)
        myColumn
    from
        (select mid,explode(myColumn) col
        from
            (select monotonically_increasing_id() mid,myColumn
            from tmp)
        )
    group by mid
"""
df = spark.sql(sql)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: This would not preserve the order I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

In pure Spark SQL, you could convert your array into a string with `concat_ws`, make the substitutions with `regexp_replace` and then recreate the array with `split`.

```sql
select split(
    regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(
            concat_ws(',', myColumn)
        , 'red', '1')
    , 'green', '2')
, ',') myColumn from df
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's create some sample data and a map that contains the substitutions: tou want to make

```scala
val df = Seq((1, Seq("red", "green")),
             (2, Seq("green", "green", "red")))
         .toDF("id", "myColumn")
val values = Map("red" -> "1", "green" -> "2")
```

The most straight forward way would be to define a UDF that does exactly what you want:

```scala
val replace = udf((x : Array[String]) =>
    x.map(value => values.getOrElse(value, value)))
df.withColumn("myColumn", replace('myColumn)).show
```

```
+---+---------+
| id| myColumn|
+---+---------+
|  1|   [1, 2]|
|  2|[2, 2, 1]|
+---+---------+
```

Without UDFs, you could transform the array into a string with `concat_ws` using separators that are not in your array. Then we could use string functions to make the edits:

```scala
val sep = ","
val replace = values
    .foldLeft(col("myColumn")){ case (column, (key, value)) =>
        regexp_replace(column, sep + key + sep, sep + value + sep) 
    }
df.withColumn("myColumn", concat(lit(sep), concat_ws(sep+sep, 'myColumn), lit(sep)))
  .withColumn("myColumn", regexp_replace(replace, "(^,)|(,$)", ""))
  .withColumn("myColumn", split('myColumn, sep+sep))
  .show
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same purely by using Spark SQL?

Comment: By sparkSQL, you mean the sparkSQL API or the actual SQL language?

Comment: The actual SQL language, my bad for being vague

Comment: No problem. I leave this here because it might help others. It has the advantage of being configurable solely with the `values` map. I added another answer with a similar approach in SQL.